# Passing value of directory from anchor tag using ActionLink to Controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to get the value of a directory/folder from anchor tag using ActionLink to my Controller.
I already encoded the value, but it always gives me 404 error.

Link text/value of {item.Folder}: \\webserver01\business\application

Value I get: %5C%5Cwebserver01%5Cbusiness%5Capplication

Original

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Folder, "OpenFolder", new { id = item.Folder }, new { @class = "", @target = "_blank" })
```

Second solution

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Folder, "OpenFolder", new { id = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(item.Folder) }, new { @class = "", @target = "_blank" })
```

Third solution

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Folder, "OpenFolder", new { id = item.Folder.Replace("%5C" "\\" }, new { @class = "", @target = "_blank" })
```

Fourth solution - Replacing %5C to 100 then replace 100 to \\ in Controller.

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Folder, "OpenFolder", new { id = item.Folder.Replace("%5C" "100" }, new { @class = "", @target = "_blank" })
```

4 solutions giving me the value: %5C%5Cwebserver01%5Cbusiness%5Capplication

Notes:

- I'm trying to open a directory in an anchor tag. It doesn't work in Chrome because of "Security Issues"
- Will use Process.Start() then open the file or directory

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to send the contents of item.folder to an action in your controller?

If so, do look into making a form with a text field for item.folder. The form method can be Get instead of Post.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the value you have from `Link text/value of {item.Folder}`:

```
\\webserver01\business\application
```

To:

```
//webserver01/business/application
```

In other words, edit your `item.Folder` that contains backslash and replace it with forward slash.

This will be the resulting HTML based on your Original Solution:

```
<a class="" href="/ControllerName/OpenFolder/webserver01/business/application" 
target="_blank">//webserver01/business/application</a>
```